# function not working after mysql upgrade

Tags: mysql, function

I have moved my mysql db to a new server, but ran into this error.

this function worked in previous version of mysql but in newer mysql gives binary errors and runs forever.

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `ddvier`$$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `HTML_strip`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`donty`@`localhost` FUNCTION `HTML_strip`(X TEXT) RETURNS TEXT CHARSET latin1
BEGIN
DECLARE sstart INT UNSIGNED;
DECLARE ENDS INT UNSIGNED;
SET sstart = LOCATE('<', X, 1);
REPEAT
SET ENDS = LOCATE('>', X, sstart);
SET X = CONCAT(SUBSTRING( X, 1 ,sstart -1) ,SUBSTRING(X, ENDS +1 )) ;
SET sstart = LOCATE('<', X, 1);
UNTIL sstart < 1 END REPEAT;
RETURN X;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: What's the exact error?

Comment: and after nearly two years, will you share it with us?

Comment: I would but I have been banned from answering my questions or asking questions